# file check script doesn't raise critical flag when file doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, scripting, nagios, nrpe

I write a little script in PowerShell for Nagios that check if file exists.
If it exists the status should be "ok", and if not it should be "critical".

The problem is when the file does not exist the status is not "critical", it shows in Nagios as "unknown".

```
$path = "c:\test\test.txt"
$critical = 2
$ok = 0

if (-not (Test-Path $path)) {
  Write-Host "file not exists"
  exit $critical
} else {
  Write-Host "file exists"
  exit $ok
}
```

Comment: how nagios get the output? by exit code or specific string?

Comment: I tested your code as it is, and it retrun 2 when not found and 0 when found, check this in powershel with the variable $LASTEXITCODE after the script end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, although I'd probably streamline it like this:

```
$path = "c:\test\test.txt"

$fileMissing = -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $path)

$msg = if ($fileMissing) {'file does not exist'} else {'file exists'}

Write-Host $msg
exit ([int]$fileMissing * 2)
```

Your problem is most likely with the way you're executing the script. If you run the script using the `-Command` parameter, like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command "&{& 'C:\path\to\your.ps1'}"
```

or like this:

```
cmd /c echo C:\path\to\your.ps1 | powershell.exe -Command -
```

the return value is 1 if an error occured, or 0 otherwise, regardless of what exitcode you set.

To have PowerShell return the correct exit code you need to add an `exit $LASTEXITCODE` to the command string:

```
powershell.exe -Command "&{& 'C:\path\to\your.ps1'; exit $LASTEXITCODE}"
```

or call the script using the `-File` parameter:

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```